# How do you compare 2 struts param in a struts if

Tags: struts2, ognl

I'm am still pretty new to struts and am having trouble trying to compare two struts params in a struts if statement. I am trying find if the current year param is equal to the checkYear param

If they are equal I want to execute some code. If they are not equal then I would like to execute some other code..

Sample code:

```
<s:param name="currentYear">
   <s:date name="%{new java.util.Date()}" format="yyyy" />
</s:param>
<s:param name="checkYear">
   <s:date format="yyyy" name="#year"/>
</s:param>
<s:if test="${checkYear == legendYear}">
  code executed
</s:if>
```

I don't really understand the purpose of the '$','%', or '{}' in the test part of the if statement if or how I need to apply it to have it check the params.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't loose the code format by editing your post in dumb ways please...

Comment: BTW, to format code, press 4 time space on each row, or paste a tabbed text, or use the Code button `{}`, or press CTRL+K

Comment: Are you sure you want param tags here, or set tags? Also, are you certain this logic belongs in the view layer? I'm skeptical.

Comment: Also this isn't a correct way to compare dates.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Struts2 tags, you use **OGNL**. [Refer to the small language guide to see how it works.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html)

In OGNL, `%{}` means you want to force the evaluation of an expression; it is needed somewhere, while it is superfluos somewhere else. In the `<s:if/>`, it is not needed, because `test=""` will evaluate its content by default.

`${}` does not exists in OGNL, it is **JSP EL**. Search on StackOverflow for some nice answer on that if you are curious.

`{}` alone in OGNL is List Projection... you probably don't need it *now*.